# How to convert dictionary [String : Any] to [String : Float] in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary like:

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["2019-04-23 22:00:00": ["2. high": 0.9535, "1. open": 0.9532, "4. close": 0.9529, "3. low": 0.9517]]
```

How I can convert the value to `[String : Double]` ??

here is pease of JSON from my question: {"Time Series FX (5min)": { "2019-04-23 23:40:00": { "1. open": "1.1223", "2. high": "1.1223", "3. low": "1.1222", "4. close": "1.1223" } } }

Comment: So, I need to grab the value like Float format

Comment: This is a nested dictionary and cannot be converted to `[String: Float]`

Comment: You have `[String: [String: Double]]`. Show the actual results that you want (in your question, not in a comment).

Comment: Show the original json response from the API.

Comment: @Igor Don't post a link in the comments. Put relevant details into your question where people will find them. Include sample input and desired output.

Comment: @Igor For the 3rd time, please do not put details in comments. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if you use cast like this:

```
let result: [String : [String: Double]]? = dict as? [String : [String: Double]]
```

but if you can't sure the dict's value type, but you need to find value which is eligible, you can use this function:

```
@inlinable public func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

like this:

```
let map = dict.values.compactMap { (value) -> [String : Double]? in
    guard let valueMap = value as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
    let filterResult = valueMap.filter { $0.value is Double }
    return filterResult as? [String : Double]
}
```